# Bond Orientational Correlation Function - how exactly to calculate

Tags: simulations, statistics, correlation-functions

I have a question about [this](https://journals.aps.org/prl/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevLett.96.028304) article.

I am trying to compute the bond order correlation function, $g_6$.
It is defined based on the bond order parameter:
$$\psi_6(r_i) = \frac{1}{N}\sum_{j}^{}{\exp[i6\theta(r_{ij})]}$$
 where:
$$g_6(r) =\langle\psi_6(0) \psi_6^*(r)\rangle .$$

and where $\theta_{ij}$ is angle between the bond-vector connecting particles i and j and an arbitrary fixed reference axis and <> denotes averaging over all pairs of particles and the index i in second equation.

so if i consider lets say 100 particles in a system, given the position ${(x,y)}$  for each particle I can find the $\psi_6(r_i)$, for example for the particle 1 there are 3 neighboring particles and the value for  $\psi_6(r_i)$ is:

$$\psi_6(r_1) = \frac{1}{3}[{\exp[i6\theta(r_{12})]+{\exp[i6\theta(r_{15})]}+{\exp[i6\theta(r_{16})}]]}= ....=a+ib$$

given the values of angles, I get a complex number such as: $a+ib$, and when i multiply by complex conjugate $a-ib$ from second formula i get a real value.

[image]

What I don't understand is how do you average second equation? How is $g_6(r)$ plotted in Figure 2b? how to bin your $r$ or position values in $x$ axis? I am confused with $\psi_6(0)$ and $\psi_6^*(r)$ what is defined as "zero" and what is $r$ ? is it the first point? does it matter where you start calculating your $\psi$s? Can you show how to calculate explicitly $g_6$ and bin data, for example in figure above?